# Serving static homepage with nginx and rest through uwsgi

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a nginx + uwsgi website (using Flask for dynamic python pages).
I would like to serve the homepage which is static directly through nginx and route everything else to uwsgi.

The following nginx configuration directives work well to serve the homepage through nginx and redirect a call to mysite.com/login to uwsgi:

```
location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                
    root  /var/www/mysite.com/static;                                                                                                                                                                
    index  index.html index.htm;                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           

location /login {                                                                                                                                                                                           
    include uwsgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                                   
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

But I can't find a way to generalize the second directive to catch all calls to mysite.com/something and direct them to uwsgi.

I tried the following which didn't work (get 404 for anything except calls to mysite.com):

```
location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                
    root  /var/www/mysite.com/static;                                                                                                                                                                
    index  index.html index.htm;                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           

location /* {                                                                                                                                                                                           
    include uwsgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                                   
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this

```
server {
...
 root  /var/www/mysite.com/static;                                                                                                                                                                
 index  index.html index.htm;   
 try_files $uri @uwsgi; 
 location @uwsgi{
    include uwsgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                                   
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031; 
 }
...
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

Comment: Thanks, after changing the **try_files** directive to `try_files $uri $uri/ @uwsgi;` it worked like a charm

Comment: NB! '$uri/' is important, and fixed the problem in my case as well (nginx 0.8.4 on Dreamhost VPS)

Comment: Is it possible to try_files only in a specific location? This could be more efficient